# CSS position absolute when GrandParent has overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

I have a div `.parent` that is horizontally scrollable. Inside this div I have multiple buttons, that need to look like this:

[image]

I am stuck at the below result, please check my progress:

```css
.wrapper {
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 7;
  max-width: 150px;
}


.inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  min-width: 67px;
}

.inner:after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  
.btn {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 14px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent"> 
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="btn">
        Button1
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="btn">
        Button2
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="btn">
        Button3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `z-index` style applied to the `.wrapper` class style. I removed the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` styles applied to the `.parent` class style. To achieve the goal, I updated the `top` style applied within the `.inner:after` class style to `-10px` and assigned the `z-index` value to `-1` and I got the result.

```css
.wrapper {
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* z-index: 3; */
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  /* overflow-x: auto;   */
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
  height: 100%;
  flex: 7;
  max-width: 220px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  min-width: 67px;
}

.inner:after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  
.btn {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 14px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent"> 
  
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="btn">
        Button1
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="btn">
        Button2
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="btn">
        Button3
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the `.parent` div has to be scrollable (when the width is less than `220px`). One more thing the red triangle should cover the border of the button. please check the screenshot